# Sort List(Double, (String, List[String])) first by Double then by first String value in the tuple

Tags: list, scala, sorting

Sort the list in scala by two conditions using inbuilt functions

**Input:**

```
List((1.2 , (C, List(A))), 
     (0.7 , (B, List(A))), 
     (0.9 , (D, List(M))), 
     (1.2 , (E, List(D,F))), 
     (0.5 , (A, List(A,C))), 
     (0.0 , (N, List(Z))))
```

If first double values is equal then sort using the first string value.
Like there are two 1.2 values so then C and E are checked

**Output:**

```
List((1.2 , (C, List(A))), 
     (1.2 , (E, List(D,F))), 
     (0.9 , (D, List(M))), 
     (0.7 , (B, List(A))) , 
     (0.5 , (A, List(A,C))), 
     (0.0 , (N, List(Z))))
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? Have you checked the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the requested order I did this:

```
input.sortWith{case (a,b) => a._1 > b._1 ||
                             a._1 == b._1 &&
                             a._2._1 < b._2._1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sortBy` like this:

```
input.sortBy{ case (d, (s, _)) => (-d, s) }
```

This extracts a new data value from the input and then sorts by that value.

This can be simpler than `sortWith` because you just need to provide the types, not the comparison functions for each type.